# Trouble Upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, 13.10

I am having trouble upgrading from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10.

I got a notification to upgrade to 13.10 and then the following happens:

- I click on the upgrade option
- give my password for authentication
- I click upgrade again when the "Welcome to Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander" page opens up
- The computer attempts to download the release tools and then nothing happens, that's it.

My computer is an Asus eee PC 1000ha netbook.  It's a 2008 model I bought in 2009.

Any suggestions?  Should I just wait for Ubuntu to work out the kinks or is there something I need to do on my end?  Any info would be great!

Comment: Sometimes the proprietary drivers are a problem. Go to System Settings -> Software & Updates choose the tab additional drivers and select the nouveau driver. Restart and try to upgrade again. For me it worked. I used to have the same problem.

Comment: Voting to close. See Launchpad [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1244802) which is a duplicate of [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1203534)

Answer (score 0):

If the ASUS Eee PC 1000HA is the same one I have, then it requires the 32-bit version. Not so sure, but for a netbook, typically just download the 32-bit ISO and perform a clean install after backing up the data. Using an external Optical drive (DVD/RW) for the install seems to work best. Never found the Eee PC all that simple to upgrade personally, but have done it this way for some time now. Don't store much on the netbook, mainly for travel.